# MongoDB $nin AND equal to certain value

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to consolidate the following

```
{
  $and : [
      {foo: {$nin: ARR_TO_EXCLUDE}},
      {foo: SOME_VAL}
]}
```

I want to query docs where `foo` unconditionally is not equal to a list of values and where it could be another value too.

Would this even make sense to consolidate?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample doc?

Comment: i think it doesn't make sense, to be done in the database, foo to pass => foo=some_val, AND foo=some_valu not in array <=> some_val not in array (you can check this before sending the query)

Comment: @Takis_ May you please clarify what you mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be replaced with a condition independ of the foo field,
and it can be done before sending the query.

```
{
  $and : [
      {foo: {$nin: ARR_TO_EXCLUDE}},
      {foo: SOME_VAL}
]}
```

<=>

```
SOME_VAL not-in ARR_TO_EXCLUDE   //(no matter what foo value has)
```

so istead of writting that $and, replace it with
something like the bellow in your driver programing language

`ARR_TO_EXCLUDE.not-contains(SOME_VAL)`

If SOME_VAL and ARR_TO_EXCLUDE are variables of the driver programming language.
If they are fields or mongodb variables then check this contition in mongodb
but its independend of the foo field